# Silverlight Toolkit: Why can't I change ItemsSource on Chart.Series?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, charts, wpftoolkit

I'm starting to experiment with the new chart controls in `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting` (from the [Silverlight 3 Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/Silverlight))

I want to bind a data table that contains a list of budgets (name & value column). It works when I first load my page:

```
<v:Chart x:Name="BudgetChart" 
         Title="Budget Distribution">
    <v:PieSeries x:Name="PieSeries" 
                 IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=CategoryName}"
                 DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
</v:Chart>
```

I bind my data to the chart like this:

```
void RefreshChart()
{ 
    PieSeries.ItemsSource = dataTable;
}
```

My problem, is that if I call `RefreshChart()` a second time, I get a bizarre exception:

> KeyNotFoundException: The given key
>   was not present in the dictionary.

Is there something I'm not doing right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually a bug with the charting controls that only manifested itself on the WPF side (works fine in Silverlight). The issue has been fixed quickly after I reported it as reported on [Delay's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2009/03/25/supporting-the-unsupported-two-fixes-for-the-unofficial-wpf-charting-assembly.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage)!